# ERROR 1064 (42000)...while cloning a database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to clone the database(in Mysql)on the same server... but get the syntax error with the below syntax .... pls correct me .

username = root
password = ''

```
 mysqldump -u root --p=  testdb9 | mysql -u root --p=  testdb5;
```

i could do it using mysqldump to sql file and back in to a new database again .... but wish to do it directly from db to db.

Answer (score 0):

The double hyphens in front of 'p' might be the problem. 
The correct syntax is either -p or --password.

Comment: No ... .tried..... mysqldump -u root -p=  testdb9 | mysql -u root -p=  testdb5; as well .... same error

Comment: Did you try "-p" instead of "-p="?

Comment: have you tried without piping the second command? I am also assuming you're running this from the command line and not inside of mysql.

Comment: this also does not work ...... do i need to give any other credentials apart from these ?? .... mysqldump  -user=root -password='' testdb5 >db4-name.out

Comment: if the password is blank don't include it in the command. mysqldump -u root > db4-out.sql

Comment: @jksloan   .....tried ....   mysqldump testdb5 -u root> db4-name.sql; .... same error again ....